# Mhchem with decimal ratios

Tags: mhchem

Without using full math-mode, does anyone know how to use the `mhchem` package with non-integer atomic subscripts.

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    %Works
    \ce{Fe98C2}     

    %Doesn't Work.
    \ce{Fe97.5C2.5} 
\end{document}
```

The Second Formula I am seeking effectively:

```
Fe$_{97.5}$C$_{2.5}$
```

Comment: \ce{Fe_{97.5}C_{2.5}} works

Comment: @Leeser Sorry, I didn't see your comment while posting my answer. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks for your generosity...I probably need the kudos more than you !!!! I will post as an answer

Comment: @ Leeser, you've beaten me for a minute, so the answer is yours:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply place the non-integer part inside curly brackets

```
\ce{Fe_{97.5}C_{2.5}}
```

As @karlkoeller mentioned in a similar answer (now deleted), the `.` is a special character inside `\ce`

Comment: Just to mention: the special character is there for specifying adducts in chemical formulae